# When you study music and drama, you study art or study arts?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

art / arts / the arts is a very confusing noun for me. I tried to get it straight by reading its definition**s** on [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/art) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/art) online dictionaries but it is clear as mud.

When you **study or teach music and drama**-> you **study art** (uncountable noun)?

When you **draw a picture** -> you **make art** (uncountable noun)?

When you like **history and literature** -> you like "**the arts**"?

When you like **history alone** -> you still like "**the arts**"?

What if you like **music and drama** -> you like **arts** without the?

You go to **college of art** to study **music** but you go to **the university of arts** to study **history**?

Comment: You don't go to a college of art to study music.

Comment: You might find something useful in the ELU question [What is the difference, if any, between 'art', 'the arts', and 'Art'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28762/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-art-the-arts-and-art)

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge range of activities that can be called "art", the creation of visual, audio or performance pieces, expressing the creator imagination, concepts or skill. If you are doing art, you are more concerned with beauty than with truth.

As a proper noun, "Art" is the name of a course in many schools teaching drawing, printing, painting and sculpture.  If you are studying Art, you are probably doing this. If you say "I like art" you probably are talking about painting etc.

"The arts" are a wide range of activities: painting, music, dance, etc. It is sometimes limited only to the most artistic type of these activities. So ballet is an art, but disco-dancing isn't always considered to be an art.  But some disagree. Likewise, some literature is an art, but not every piece of writing.

History is generally considered to be a humanity, and not an art. Philosophy, literature, English, French and so on are all humanities. Geography is a social science, Physics, biology and chemistry are natural sciences.

Many non-arts have aspects which emphasise creativity, imagination and skill. So it does not seem strange to talk about "the art of computer programming", if you are talking about the creative aspect, and not the technical. Likewise many arts have technical, and non-artistic aspects.

So if you like (classical) music and drama, you like (some of) the arts.

If you study music and drama you are not studying Art (even though they are arts)

When you draw a picture you might create art (or a piece of art, or artwork). Only the artist can decide if it is art.

You go to a College of Art to study painting, printing, sculpture and drawing. You go to a College of Music (or a Conservatory) to study Music.

There is an older meaning of "art" which included everything done with skill (including science and the humanities) In this old meaning, a College might offer a "Bachelor of Art" (or BA) degree even though the subject studied was not an art in the modern sense.  Similarly colleges in the USA offer courses in "Liberal Arts", which is a general study of science, social science, arts and humanities.

So "art" usually is painting etc.  "The arts", or "an art" is Art, music, drama etc.